# Admob interstitial ad show on breakpoint

Tags: android, admob

I have a `GameOverActivity` in my game and I want to show an `InterstitialAd` in its `onCreate()`. For this I need to load it somewhere else because it won't display. How do I do that?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    //admob
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            //requestNewInterstitial
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
            onResume();
        }
    });
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
        onPause();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code wont work because Interstitial Ad take sometime to be downloaded. So, Google recommends to download it first and display it later.

So, I think you should display it before calling GameOverActivity (download it and display it on previous Activity..

**For Example:**

During onCreate() function from previous Activity, you request the Ad (it will be downloaded and it will take sometime).

Then, before starting GameOverActivity, you first show the InterstitialAd. After the ad is closed, then, you start the GameOverActivity.

```
public class MainActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("AD_UNIT_ID");
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // Start GameOverActivity when the ad is closed
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameOverActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
     }

    // You probably have some function from where you start GameOverActivity
    private void methodCalledWhenUserLoses() {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            // If loaded, show it. GameOverActivity will be started when ad is closed
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        } else {
            // If ad was not loaded yet, shows show GameOverActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameOverActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
     }

}
```

Code above is a example.

Interstitial Ad Example can be found at:

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/interstitial